# Adding XML billing keys to Meteor Android APK files

Tags: android, cordova, meteor, in-app

I'm trying to add an in-app purchase to a Meteor app using the Cordova Purchase Plugin (https://github.com/j3k0/cordova-plugin-purchase)

As part of the Android setup I need to add an XML file to the project - platform/android/res/values/billing_key.xml

I've set up a folder in my meteor root called 'cordova-build-override' and in that I've built the folder structure to match so that my valid billing_key.xml file is dropped there as part of a build.

However, when I try to test my in-app purchase on my android device (on a signed, aligned, installed .apk file) I get the following error:

```
D/CordovaPurchase( 3389): Num SKUs Found: 1
D/CordovaPurchase( 3389): Product SKU Added: com.obfuscated.app.product_id
D/CordovaPurchase( 3389): init start
W/ResourceType( 3389): No package identifier when getting value for resource number 0x00000000
E/PluginManager( 3389): Uncaught exception from plugin
E/PluginManager( 3389): android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: String resource ID #0x0
```

I'm pretty sure that this is because the billing key isn't being bundled into the apk. I've uploaded my .apk to the google play developer center, so I don't think that's the problem(?)

Am I right? If so, how can I fix it? Or if I'm wrong, what's happening here?

Comment: OK so according to the updated docs I no longer need to add the billing_key.xml file, I simply need to make sure that I declare the plugin and my billing key inside my main config.xml, so I've updated the meteor-config.js file to reflect this, but still no dice. Has anyone else had any experience with in-app purchasing in a meteor mobile app?

Comment: any luck? i'm looking forward to this answer :P

Comment: Sorry I ended up doing two builds, one free and one paid as i couldn't get this to work at all

Comment: makes sense ( :
i would love to find a meteor solution with in app purchase solution //=